# Opening of Modal Window pushes down rest of Elements from the main Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have a Modal Window which is being open upon clicking on a button located on the main page. The Modal Window is open with the help of a router-view. However, upon opening the Modal Window, my `<hr class="header-line">` from the main page is being pushed down with the rest of the elements (I have included only the header line for simplicity). How can I avoid this?

```
 <div>
 <button v-on:click="openModal()">Begin</button>
 <AccCreation v-if="showModal" :wal="wal" :showModal=showModal v-on:closeMod="onChildClick()"></AccCreation>
 </div>
 <div id="nav">
   <Navigation></Navigation>
 </div>
 <div>
  <hr class="header-line">
 </div>
 <div>
  <router-view/>
 </div>
```

Comment: means your modal isn't really a modal, it's being inserted into the normal document flow

Comment: Is it a homebrewed modal? Probably needs to be css `position: fixed`. If it is homebrew, consider using a modal library.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. How can one display it, if not be inserting it in the normal document flow? (Sorry, I am new to node.js)

Comment: The top Div is actually position: fixed;

Comment: It does look modal to me, sitting on top of my main page.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what was happening. I had given the same "header" name to a Div element (`<div id="header">`) on both the main page and the modal window, which is inserted into the main page, to which I had added some padding in the CSS of the modal window, which padding was thus added to the header in the main window (I hadn't actually defined any CSS in the main window), explaining why my elements were shifting down.